# Alternative for "capture" which doesn't suppress the output if the code works

Tags: stata

I have a question concerning Stata. I'm executing a loop in which there might be an error. Whether the error occurs depends on the data at hand. Unfortunately I do not know exactly how the data, which my code is used for, looks like. I only know the variables which are in the data. So I use the command `capture` to let my do-file run even if an error occurs. But if I use this command, Stata also suppresses the output if the command sometimes works in my loop. Of course, that is not what I want.
My command looks like:

```
capture list year JCage`x' numberfirmsage`x' AvSizeAge`x'
```

and is part of a loop. So what can I do in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for `capture` tells you that this is done by `capture noisily`.